# Node inspector doesn't start

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

I run NodeJS Express server on 127.0.0.1:3000 and trying to debug it with awesome (when it works) [Node Inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) but having trouble starting it after the update. I used to run version of Node Inspector 0.7.4 with `node-debug server.js` with no problems. Then I wanted to update it to latest 0.10.0 and went `npm update -g node-inspector` but now when I run node-debug server.js blank page opens in browser with url `http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5858` and nothing happens. I tried `node-debug --web-host=127.0.0.1:3000` with no luck.

How can I debug my my Node programs now? BTW I'm on Ubuntu.

**EDIT:** 
I had no luck running latest version 0.10.0 so I had to uninstal and install 0.9.2. Node inspector started with no problem then. I run 0.10.0 on my mac but on Ubuntu it doesn't seem to work for some reason so going back to 0.9.2 was only solution. I hope this will help some Ubuntu users.

Comment: It works for me, it just took a few moments to appear. tried in windows 7 x64 with node-inspector version 0.10.0. node.js version 0.12.0

Comment: @Kevin B As per my edit I had to go back to 0.9.2 and then it runs fine. Must have something to do with Ubuntu as 0.10.0 runs fine on my mac.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome 42.0.2311.152-1 with node-inspector v0.9.2 or higher to fix this problem on Ubuntu 14.04.

See here: https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/697